# Open the settings panel with a keyboard shortcut

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

How can I set a keyboard shortcut to open this settings panel in Gnome?

[image: gnome settings panel]

I figure I could just use a custom shell shortcut, but I can't for the life of me find a command to cause this panel to open.

Is there a shell command to open this panel?